# Bash variable character replacement ends up to an empty string or a command not valid

Tags: macos, bash, ubuntu, vagrant

I am working on a shell script to retrieve variable content from a JSON file via JQ. The JSON file is in string format (no matter whether this is a real string or a number) and to retrieve the variable in my bash script I did something like this

```
my_domain=$(cat /vagrant/data_bags/config.json | jq ."app"[0]."domain")
```

The above code once echoed results in "mydomain" with a beginning and a trailing quote sign. I though this was a normal behaviour of the echo command. However, while concatenating my variable with another shell command the system raise an error. For instance, the following command

```
cp /vagrant/public_html/index.php "/var/www/"+$my_domain+"/index.php"
```

fails with the following error

```
cp: cannot create regular file `/var/www/+"mydomain"+/index.php': No such file or directory
```

At this stage, I wasn't able to identify whether it's me doing the wrong concatenation with the plus sign or the variable is effectively including the quotes that in any case will end up generating an error.

I have tried to replace the quotes in my variable, but I ended up getting the system raising a "Command not found" error.

Can somebody suggest what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`+` is not used for string concatenation in bash (or perl, or php).  Just:

```
cp /vagrant/public_html/index.php "/var/www/$my_domain/index.php"
```

Embedding a variable inside a double-quoted text string is known as *interpolation*, and is one of the reasons why we need the `$` prefix, to indicate that this is a variable.  Interpolation is specifically not done inside single quoted strings.

Braces `${my_domain}` are not required because the `/` directory separators are not valid characters in a variable name, so there is no ambiguity.

For example:

```
var='thing'
echo "Give me your ${var}s"    # Correct, appends an 's' after 'thing'
echo "Give me your $vars"      # incorrect, looks for a variable called vars.
```

If a variable (like 'vars') does not exist then (by default) it will not complain, it will just give an empty string.  Braces (graph brackets) are required more in c-shell (csh or tcsh) because of additional syntax for modifying variables, which involves special trailing characters.

Comment: Thanks for your time in explaining the difference and fixing my mistake.

Comment: so embracing a variable in graph brackets is required when there could be an ambiguity with the preceding or the following character? Can you pass a wrong example so I can't understand this better? Thanks

Comment: @AndreaMoro:  adding example in the answer

Comment: Ok, thanks for amending the example. The variable is imported correctly as expected, but I still have the problem the source var arrives as "myvar" with the quotes. Am I doing something else wrong? Perhaps it's a problem of the JQ library or the way I use to read the value?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use `+` to concatenate string in bash, change your command to

```
cp /vagrant/public_html/index.php "/var/www/"${my_domain}"/index.php"
```

Comment: The variable is imported correctly as expected, but I still have the problem the source var arrives as "myvar" with the quotes. Am I doing something else wrong? Perhaps it's a problem of the JQ library or the way I use to read the value?

Answer (score 0):

My problem was not related only to the wrong concatenation, but also to the JQ library that after parsing the value from the JSon file was returning text between quotes.

In order to avoid JQ doing this, just add the -rawoutput parameter when calling JQ.